# Could not find artifact and could not resolve dependencies

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, war

I'm working in a maven project which contains many dependencies, i have a dependency from a centralized **remote NEXUS repository** ,so i should have a specific configuration in my **setting.xml**..
so When i launch **clean install** from the maven tab in intellij it displays errors:

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project calender: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.orange:calender:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could
>   not find artifact com.francetelecom.clara.component:security:jar:3.0.0
>   in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

but when i switch to the Terminal tab in intellij  the build succeed without errors and when i try to deploy the war within Tomcat it won't.
Tomcat log:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.commons.collections.ArrayStack: method (I)V not found
>     at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.(Digester.java:150)   at
>   com.francetelecom.clara.security.config.SecurityConfig.parse(SecurityConfig.java:95)
>     at
>   com.francetelecom.clara.security.SecurityManager.initialize(SecurityManager.java:114)
>     at
>   com.francetelecom.clara.security.SecurityManager.(SecurityManager.java:99)
>     at
>   com.francetelecom.clara.security.SecurityManager.getContextInstance(SecurityManager.java:371)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running maven from maven tab in IntelliJ, you use the settings you find from Alt/Ctrl S -> Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven

When running from terminal in IntelliJ it will use first mvn you find on PATH and use configuration from what you get there. "mvn -version" from terminal will show you your Maven Home when running mvn from terminal